# Problemas con GROUP BY e IF

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo la siguiente consulta donde intento agrupar un conductor con sus respectivas certificaciones. El problema es que al ejecutar no muestra nada mas que el id del conductor y su nombre. No muestra las fechas de vencimiento de cada certificacion del conductor.

Cuando saco el GROUP BY de la consulta, si muestra las fechas pero repitiendo el mismo conductor en nuevas filas de la consulta.

Agradecería su ayuda para ver qué está sucediendo.

El atributo cc.estado_certi_conductor = 0 hace referencia a una certificación vigente, que son las que se desean visualizar.

```
SELECT c.id_conductor, CONCAT(c.nombre_conductor,' ',c.apellidoPat_conductor,' ',c.apellidoMat_conductor),
                   IF(tc.nombre_tipo_certificacion = 'A' AND cc.estado_certi_conductor = 0, cc.fechaVenc_certi_conductor, '') as a,
                   IF(tc.nombre_tipo_certificacion = 'B' AND cc.estado_certi_conductor = 0, cc.fechaVenc_certi_conductor, '') as b,
                   IF(tc.nombre_tipo_certificacion = 'C' AND cc.estado_certi_conductor = 0, cc.fechaVenc_certi_conductor, '') as c,
                   IF(tc.nombre_tipo_certificacion = 'D' AND cc.estado_certi_conductor = 0, cc.fechaVenc_certi_conductor, '') as d,
                   IF(tc.nombre_tipo_certificacion = 'E' AND cc.estado_certi_conductor = 0, cc.fechaVenc_certi_conductor, '') as e,
                   IF(tc.nombre_tipo_certificacion = 'F' AND cc.estado_certi_conductor = 0, cc.fechaVenc_certi_conductor, '') as f,
                   IF(tc.nombre_tipo_certificacion = 'G' AND cc.estado_certi_conductor = 0, cc.fechaVenc_certi_conductor, '') as g
            FROM conductor c 
            INNER JOIN base b ON b.id_base = c.id_base
            LEFT JOIN certificacion_conductor cc ON cc.id_conductor = c.id_conductor
            LEFT JOIN tipo_certificacion_conductor tc ON tc.id_tipo_certificacion = cc.id_tipo_certificacion
            WHERE b.nombre_base = 'NOMBRE BASE'
            GROUP BY c.id_conductor
```

Si saco el Group By la tabla resultado me queda de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con Group By:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Dudo que tu consulta sea conforme al estándar SQL. Aunque en MySQL pueda funcionar porque es más permisivo, sugiero que siempre pruebes tus consultas con el modo `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` activado. Esto se hace poniendo esto antes de la consulta: `SET sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY';` A continuación tu consulta. Si no deja ejecutarla y da error, oblígate a corregirla. ¿Por qué? Porque la permisividad de MySQL deja que escribamos consultas no estándar de SQL y a veces eso corresponde a un problema mucho más serio: un diseño erróneo de la base de datos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que te estaría faltando, es una función de agregación. El problema tiene que ver con lo que te comentó A. Cedano, el modo "permisivo" te induce a cometer errores. El `group_by` debiera especificar cada una de las columnas por las que buscas agrupar, cualquier otra cosa o no va en el `SELECT ...` o corresponde usar una función de agregación

```
SELECT c.id_conductor, 
       CONCAT(c.nombre_conductor,' ',c.apellidoPat_conductor,' ',c.apellidoMat_conductor),
       MAX(IF(tc.nombre_tipo_certificacion = 'A' AND cc.estado_certi_conductor = 0, cc.fechaVenc_certi_conductor, '')) as a,
       MAX(IF(tc.nombre_tipo_certificacion = 'B' AND cc.estado_certi_conductor = 0, cc.fechaVenc_certi_conductor, '')) as b,
       MAX(IF(tc.nombre_tipo_certificacion = 'C' AND cc.estado_certi_conductor = 0, cc.fechaVenc_certi_conductor, '')) as c,
       MAX(IF(tc.nombre_tipo_certificacion = 'D' AND cc.estado_certi_conductor = 0, cc.fechaVenc_certi_conductor, '')) as d,
       MAX(IF(tc.nombre_tipo_certificacion = 'E' AND cc.estado_certi_conductor = 0, cc.fechaVenc_certi_conductor, '')) as e,
       MAX(IF(tc.nombre_tipo_certificacion = 'F' AND cc.estado_certi_conductor = 0, cc.fechaVenc_certi_conductor, '')) as f,
       MAX(IF(tc.nombre_tipo_certificacion = 'G' AND cc.estado_certi_conductor = 0, cc.fechaVenc_certi_conductor, '')) as g
       FROM conductor c 
       INNER JOIN base b ON b.id_base = c.id_base
       LEFT JOIN certificacion_conductor cc ON cc.id_conductor = c.id_conductor
       LEFT JOIN tipo_certificacion_conductor tc ON tc.id_tipo_certificacion = cc.id_tipo_certificacion
       WHERE b.nombre_base = 'NOMBRE BASE'
       GROUP BY c.id_conductor,
                CONCAT(c.nombre_conductor,' ',c.apellidoPat_conductor,' ',c.apellidoMat_conductor)
```

Detalle

- En primer lugar, hemos agregado todas las columnas por las que deseamos agrupar.
- En cuanto a las fechas, no las puedes agrupar ya que cada una se expandiría en una nueva fila, puedes en este caso usar la función de agregación `MAX()`, siempre te traerá la última para cada tipo de fecha.

Comment: Su consulta me entrega la respuesta que necesitaba. Muchas gracias, funciona a la perfección.